# How to set the size and perform testing with lower or higher resolution?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How to set the size and perform testing with lower or higher resolution while executing scripts in GIT with pace automation framework?

Answer (score 0):

The users would be able to customize the browser size in the init.properties file using the property “browser.window.custom.size” by declaring the required dimension (width and height).

```
browser.window.custom.size=width,height
```